# three digit page number

Tags: page, number

I want the pages of my document to be labeled like 001,002, ... ,099,100, instead of 1,2, ... ,99,100. How do I get such a triple-digit pattern? I've already tried `\ifnum\value{mycounter}<10 0\fi\arabic{mycounter}` which doesn't yield what I seek.

Comment: Welcome! Do you also want that `\pageref{<label>}` yields a three digit number?

Comment: Yes, that would be great

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define a suitable counter representation that expands to three digits: add a 0 if the number is less than 100 and a further one if the number is less than 10.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % for small pictures

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\arabicthree}[1]{\expandafter\@arabicthree\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@arabicthree}[1]{\ifnum #1<100 0\fi\ifnum #1<10 0\fi\number#1}
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{arabicthree}

\begin{document}

text \pageref{first} and \pageref{second}

\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{42}

text\label{first}

\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{333}

text\label{second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Done the edit.